# Lookup map for converting Strings into Android `R.raw` integers

Tags: java, android

I'm currently working on an Android app and I need to translate keys of type `String` to `Integers` which are determined at compile time of `R.raw`.
Right now I have found two ways of creating such a `Map` that holds all (needed) values of `R.raw`:

```
private static final Map<String, Integer> map = ImmutableMap.<String, Integer>builder()
                                                .put("...", R.raw.id)
                                                 ... 
                                                .build();
```

and

```
private static final Map<String, Integer> map = new ArrayMap<>();
static {
    map.put("...", R.raw.id);
    ...
}
```

My questions are:

- Are there better ways of creating a `Map` to lookup keys and return values that are determined at compile time? I don't want to use reflection.
  and
- Which one of those ways would you prefer?

Comment: Because you are mentioning raw, I would suggest placing your files in assets folder, you can reference them by filename from the AssetManager. Then you can just use a List of Strings and you don't need to create a Map.

Comment: @user1281750 you might add this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is not such thing as `ArrayMap` in standard Java. Therefore, I am just going to assume that you meant `HashMap`.

---

I would choose neither of those options. Depending on how many elements you need to insert into that `Map`, you could end up with a big chunk of code that is just a group of `add` calls.

I recommend creating two arrays: one of the `String`s, and one of the `Integer`s.

Then, all you have to do is create a loop that inserts all the values into the map.

Here is what I came up with:

```
String[] foos = {...};
Integer[] bars = {...};
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for(int i = 0, length = foo.length; i < length; i++) {
    map.put(foos[i], bars[i]);
}
```

Comment: `ArrayMap` is a more memory efficient `HashMap` designed for Android. I'm currently checking user1281750's approach, but your's might come in handy, when you can't move resources to assets (in Android).

Comment: @GiantTree Ah, I see. I was wondering where `ArrayMap` was coming from (I am not experienced with Android).